# Oblique view of an {x,y} and {x,z} plot : is ListPointPlot3D the right strategy?

Tags: plotting, visualization

Seeking advice for how to construct an oblique chart plot of {x,y} and {x,z} value lists in a 3D View where the viewer can trace a line from {x,y,0} to {x,0,0}, and then jump to the associated {x,0,z} value.

Idea here is to present two related variables sharing a common x-value on one graphic.

In the following sample code of 10 points (although I typically have to present hundreds of points), I have two (possibly 3) issues in my code:

1. {x,0,z} points are correctly connected via the line to their corresponding {x,0,0} point.  How do I specify the same for the {x,y,0} points so that they match up with their corresponding {x,0,0} point?
2. How do I eliminate the bounding 3D Box view?
3. Am I completely headed in the wrong direction (e.g., I should generate 2D ListPointPlots and then "marry" them at the X-Axis by projecting each as the inside face of a 3D cube)?

```
values[{x, z}] = Table[{i, 0, RandomInteger[{10, 15}]}, {i, 0, 10}];
values[{x, y}] = Table[{i, RandomInteger[{1, 10}], 0}, {i, 0, 10}];
ListPointPlot3D[{values[{x, z}], values[{x, y}]}
 , Filling -> Axis
 , AxesLabel -> {"X-Axis", "Y-Axis", "Z-Axis"}
 , ViewPoint -> {0, 2, 2.75}
 , ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0.04}]
```

Attached is a reference example for an Oblique data chart of two variables relative to a common X-Value.

[image: Oblique Chart of Systolic and Diastolic Blood Pressure]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start:

```
valxz = Table[{i, 0, RandomInteger[{10, 15}]}, {i, 0, 10}];
valxy = Table[{i, RandomInteger[{1, 10}], 0}, {i, 0, 10}];
Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.03],
  Point[valxy], Point[valxz], Thickness[0.01],
  Line[{{{1, 0, 0} #, #}}] & /@ valxy, 
  Line[{{{1, 0, 0} #, #}}] & /@ valxz
  }, Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

[image]

You may beatify it using e.g. Color, Style e.t.c.

Comment: Oh -- this is GREAT!!!  THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Did you mean *beatify* or *beautify*?  I suspect the latter, but like the former rather more!

Comment: Well, I suppose it is nor good enough for the former.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using [`Tube`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tube.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

values[{x, z}] = Table[{i, 0, RandomInteger[{10, 15}]}, {i, 0, 10}];
values[{x, y}] = Table[{i, RandomInteger[{1, 10}], 0}, {i, 0, 10}];

Graphics3D[{
  CapForm["Square"],
  Tube[{ReplacePart[#, 3 -> 0], #}, 1/4] & /@ values[{x, z}],
  Tube[{ReplacePart[#, 2 -> 0], #}, 1/4] & /@ values[{x, y}]},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"X-Axis", "Y-Axis", "Z-Axis"},
 ViewPoint -> {1, 1.7, 2.75},
 ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0.04},
 Boxed -> False,
 AxesEdge -> {Automatic, {1, -1}, {1, -1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Bob -- THANK YOU -- that is fantastic as well!

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1];
systolic = ReverseSort /@ RandomInteger[{70, 180}, {24, 2}];
diastolic = ReverseSort /@ RandomInteger[{40, 120}, {24, 2}];
```

We can use [`PairedBarChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PairedBarChart.html) and post-process the output to get a 3D look as in the example in OP:

```
barspacing = {0, 2, 0};

pbc = PairedBarChart[systolic, diastolic, 
   BarOrigin -> "XAxis", 
   BarSpacing -> barspacing, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
   ImagePadding -> 50,
   ImageSize -> Large, 
   ChartStyle -> {Directive[EdgeForm[{Opacity[1], Black}], Black, HatchFilling[Pi/4, 1]],
    Directive[EdgeForm[{Opacity[1], Black}], GrayLevel[.7]]}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["systolic", 14], 
       {-2 (3 + barspacing[[2]]), 75}, {Center, Bottom}, {0, 1}],
    Text[Style["diastolic", 14], 
       {-2 (3 + barspacing[[2]]), -75}, {Center, Top}, {0, -1}], 
    Line[{{0, 70}, {1 + (2 + barspacing[[2]]) Length @ systolic , 70}}],
    Text[Style[70, 14], Offset[{5, 0},
       {1 + (2 + barspacing[[2]]) Length @ systolic, 70}], {Left, Center}], 
    Line[{{0, -40}, {1 + (2 + barspacing[[2]]) Length @ systolic, -40}}], 
    Text[Style[40, 14], Offset[{5, 0}, 
       {1 + (2 + barspacing[[2]]) Length@systolic , -40}], {Left, Center}]}]
```

[image]

Use [`ShearingTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShearingTransform.html) to modify the rectangle, line and text primitives in the lower panel:

```
pbc /. rlt : (_Rectangle | _Line | _Text ) /; Not[FreeQ[rlt, {_, _?Negative}]] :> 
    GeometricTransformation[rlt, ShearingTransform[3 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]
```

[image]

An alternative approach using the option [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html):

```
st = ShearingTransform[5 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}];

bs = 1;
pbc1 = PairedBarChart[systolic -> ChartElementData["Rectangle"], 
  diastolic -> (GeometricTransformation[ChartElementData["Rectangle"][##], st] &),
 Axes -> False,
 BarSpacing -> {0, bs, 0}, 
 BarOrigin -> "XAxis", 
 ImageSize -> 800, 
 ChartElementFunction -> (#3[[1]][##] &)]
```

[image]

We can construct the axes using [`AxisObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html):

```
axes = AxisObject[Line[{{0, 0}, #}], {0, #2}, 
     AxisLabel -> Placed[Style[#3, 16], {0.5, {0.5, -1.25}}], 
     RotateLabel -> #4 Degree , 
     TickDirection -> "Outward", 
     TickLabelPositioning -> "Tip", 
     AxisStyle -> FontSize -> 16] & @@@ 
  {{st[{0, -Max @ diastolic}], Max@diastolic, "diastolic", 55 }, 
   {{0, Max @ systolic}, Max @ systolic, "systolic", 90 }};
```

and add `axes` and other annotations using the option `Epilog`:

```
Show[pbc1, 
 Epilog -> {axes, 
   Line[{{0, 70}, {(2 + bs) Length @ systolic, 70}}], 
   Text[Style[70, 16], {1 + (2 + bs) Length @ systolic, 70}, {-1, 0}], 
   Line[st /@ {{0, -40}, {(2 + bs) Length @ systolic, -40}}], 
   Text[Style[40, 16], st @ {1 + (2 + bs) Length @ systolic, -40}, {-1, 0}]}, 
 ImagePadding -> 60]
```

[image]

Comment: WOW!  THIS is true to the original example!  I know there are so many ways to generate plots in Mathematica, but this blows me away having one question and three distinctly different answers -- all of which are GREAT!  Thank you!